# Stream Processing with Statistical Functions

Tags: c#, .net, statistics, inputstream

I am writing an application that interprets a time delayed stream of data. The data arrives at consistent intervals, and each data packet consists of 3 primitive values.

I need to process this stream to calculate a value every time a new packet arrives.
The calculation includes the need to include 'look-back' values, hence it may only produce an output value after a given number of packets have arrived.
The types of functions I apply to the buffered data include, SD, MEAN(OVER RANGE), MAX/MIN etc, all basic statistical functions.

I have coded this using buffers, but I am thinking - what I am basically building is a fixed function pipeline... this must have been done before in .net...

Is there some library that I can use to 'fluently' (preferably) construct my function pipeline, and then simply pump packets into it, and read out the various results that are generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) (Rx) may be what you are looking for. Rx allows you to apply Linq (i.e. a "fluent" API) to a stream of data. It also allows you to define the length of your buffer if you for example wish to calculate a running average over a window of the latest 100 observations (what you call "look-back" values).

There are a couple of [videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611) on Channel9 to get you started. [This one](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Rx-Workshop/Rx-Workshop-Event-Processing) shows how to do calculations based on "look-back" values.

Answer (score 1):

The Reactive Extensions library may be helpful for what you are trying to do, as it provides a way to use Linq operators over asynchronous data streams.  You could use the Buffer operator to only return a value after a specified number of items have arrived, i.e:

```
var seq = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var bufSeq = seq.Buffer(5);
bufSeq.Subscribe(values => Console.WriteLine(values.Sum()));
Console.ReadKey();
```

There are more examples and information on the Reactive website:

[Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)

Comment: Thanks Matthew - I have taken a look and this does indeed process my stream for me. My data-set arrives at the rate of 100Hz, and the full calculation will run every 200 samples, does RX incur any significant overhead? I was previously using simple ring-buffers (fixed length queues), and performance was extremely quick - are there any performance implications given RX is wrapping the primitive data items in 'observables'?